# Where is the OS platform after downloading the Debian Linux app from the Microsoft app store?

Tags: linux, debian, debian-installer

I downloaded the Debian Linux app on my computer from the Microsoft app store however the only thing that appeared after entering my username and password was the command prompt. I understand that Linux is mostly operated using the CLI, however I was expecting some type of virtual machine box that will allow me to access the new operating system. Or should I ditch the whole app and try installing the platform from the original www.debian.org and create a partition in my Windows disk. I fear that I may lose all my data in my current Windows OS if I do that which is why I'm wondering if I should proceed. Although I'm going to take a guess that it gives the option of running either Linux or Windows when booting up the computer.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Unix and Linux stack exchange site! Please [visit the Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) for information on how to best post on this site. I take it when you say that you installed Debian via the Windows Store, you mean you enabled [WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)? This is a sort of compatibility layer giving you access to a Linux kernel and some tools as a sort of subsystem not a virtual machine or full install of Linux. A GUI could be installed here but you should consider using virtual machine software to install Linux

Comment: What sources do you recommend or should I refer to the original debian website? Thanks for the newcomer feedback :)

Comment: I would recommend that you install a virtual machine platform such as [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or enable [Hyper-V](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v) if possible and install a copy of [Debian](https://www.debian.org/distrib/) that you get from here. The standard netinstall image is fine, you can choose to install a graphical environment of your choice during the install process. Use the wiki's and other sources of documentation for reference of the Virtual Machine Software and Distro repectively to assist you.

Comment: Thanks! I'm about to install the virtual machine from the link in your last comment, and lastly do you recommend Ubuntu over Debian or vice versa?

Comment: I prefer Debian, however Ubuntu has a larger community, there is a sister site askubuntu dedicated to Ubuntu questions and issues. It is more preconfigured for you with "reasonable" defaults. Debian is more stripped down and basic which is why so many distros are based off it. Any maintained and supported distros are great. Fedora, CentOS, Manjaro, etc. Jump around and try them if you want. The great thing with virtual machines is if you have the disk space you could install them all potentially. And if you run into issues you also can fall back to Windows without having to reboot.

Comment: Remember to look for official documentation first, then Wiki's, and lastly here on stack exchange if you have issues. This [advice](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) has helped me a lot.